# Java: How to treat generic heterogeneous containers?

Tags: java, generics

While dealing with heterogeneous containers (i.e. database cursor with strings, ints etc.), what (and **why**) is better approach:

```
Vector<?>
```

or

```
Vector<Object>
```

You can substitute Vector for any other Collection, that's just example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're comparing. Trying to create a vector like

```
    java.util.Vector<?> v = new java.util.Vector<?>();
```

gets an error, `Cannot instantiate the type Vector<?>`

If you use `<?>` in a parameter list (without using the super keyword) that means you can't insert anything into the collection. If you use `<Object>` then you can insert and remove things.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Gonna remove my answer, it's incorrect. Also, Achewood avatar ftw.

Comment: But: If you use `<?>` in a method argument, then it accepts all types. If you use `<Object>` then it accepts *only* `<Object>`.

Comment: There was not a statement that this was a method argument in the question. If it was, they yes having `Vector<? extends Object>` might be a good idea.

Comment: More generally for any type `X`, you can only retrieve `X` from `Vector<? extends X>` and only insert `X` into `Vector<? super X>`. But you can *both* insert and retrieve `X` to/from `Vector<X>`. In this particular example you can see that `?` is just shorthand notation for `? extends Object`, so follows this answer.

Answer (score 5):

use `Vector<Object>`. The `?` wildcard should be used when you are writing code that does not know what is the generic type of the collection. You cannot create a `new Vector<?>` so why hold it as such. You know you want a collection that will hold any `Object` so declare it as such.

Answer (score 3):

`Vector<Object>` is a heterogeneous container.

`Vector<?>` is a homogenous container of unknown type.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<?>` is the super type of all kind of `Collection` including `Collection<?>`

Using `Collection<?>` allows you to get the content of the collection which will always be at least an Object.

But as Nathan said using `Collection<?>` will not allows you to add or remove elements. Because any parameter pass to add or remove would have to be a subtype of this unknown type (`<?>`). Since we don’t know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type.

So if you only need to consult the content of the `Collection` you can use wilcard type but if you want to add/remove some elements you have to use `Collection<Object>`.